# How to select adjacent element via XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

There is Dropdown list with the following code. How to write XPath for this element?

```
<div class="dropdown ">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-block" type="button">
        <!-- react-text: 346 -->
        Select door
        <!-- /react-text -->
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"/>
     </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want `Select door` button ??

Comment: OP seems to want to select the unfortunately incomplete *Dropdown list* `div`, but, yes, we shouldn't have to guess.  Anyway, I [**show how to select this `div` as well as the `button` before it**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38896577/290085).

Comment: It is a dropdown with Button tag. 'Select door' is the default text displayed in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//button[normalize-space() = 'Select door']
```

will select the shown `button` element based on its *Select door* label.

This XPath,

```
//button[normalize-space()='Select door']/following-sibling::div[@class='dropdown-menu'][1]
```

will select the immediately following `dropdown-menu` `div`.